# URL scraping with Selenium, problems with a load more button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to perform URL scraping of CSV files contained in a website. The website has a 'load more' button that forced me into trying out selenium instead of the requests or bs4 packages.

However, my code does not always work: sometimes it works smoothly, sometimes only part of the URLs are downloaded, (like if I didn't click the 'load more' button all the necessary times). I tried to increase the wait time with `time.sleep(5)`, but it didn't work. Maybe I placed those in the wrong part of the code?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Initializing Selenium WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Opening the website
driver.get('https://example/csv_depository/')  

# Clicking the "Load More" button until it's not possible anymore, 
# XPATH of the load more button was found on the webpage sourcecode
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        load_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/button")
        load_more_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Loading complete')
        break

time.sleep(5)
# Extract all the URLs from the webpage
links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')]
time.sleep(5)

# Filter URLs of csv files
csv_links = [link for link in links if link.endswith('.csv')]
unique_dict = dict.fromkeys(csv_links)
csv_links = list(unique_dict.keys())
csv_links = ['Links'] + csv_links

# Check if all URLs have been downloaded
howmany = len(csv_links)
print(f"{howmany} URLs were downloaded")
```

Comment: Confirm the website, otherwise this is not debuggable.